# Why some unused functions are in Yellow in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, dao

I am using Room database in my app. All the functions in DAO interface are in yellow. But when I want to see where they are used, I see that some of them haven't any usage. In Android Studio functions which are not invoked are in White but why here they are in Yellow?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think they are the override methods .all override methods are yellow 
At" the end chetori irani :)   "

Comment: Thanks Tohid, where is it overridden?! When I add a new Query it is in White not Yellow.